# How do I convert a number to an exponent?

Tags: python

For my 'intro to coding class', our assignment is to calculate how far (meters) light travels in one year. I currently have completed that, however I am having trouble converting my large answer into an exponent form. we are using the newest form of python on a website called MindTap. How would I go about converting my answer into exponent form?

Here is my code for the assignment

```
secinyear = float(365*24*60**2)
rate = float(3*10**8)
cal = (secinyear * rate)

print("Light travels ", cal, "meters in a year.")
```

cal come out to be 9460800000000000.0. I wish to turn this into a proper exponent form such as 9.4608 x 10^15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the string formatting method in python:

```
print(f"Light travels {cal:.2e} meters in a year.")
```

Output:

```
Light travels 9.46e+15 meters in a year.
```

Answer (score 2):

Does something like this meet your needs?

```
value = 2857434.93485
print("{:.2e}".format(value))
```

The result is `2.86e+06`